# As [adjective] as it sounds

Tags: phrase-meaning

I realize that it's a common phrase, it couldn't be wrong, and I'm not saying it is. Yet I just can't help but wonder, is there a word left out? Could this phrase be re-written some other way?

Like saying:

> As horrible as it sounds, their true intention was to steal from us!

Does it mean: It is as horrible as it sounds, their true intention...

Or: I'm saying this regardless of how horrible it may sound...

I googled it and looked up some dictionaries but couldn't find something that would help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the idiom can be used to say **regardless of how horrible it may sound** it's true, and it can also be used to say **it wasn't so bad**

> P1: Their true intention was to steal from us!
>   P2: Really?! That's just horrible!
>   P1: Well, **as horrible as it sounds**, it was.
>
> **As horrible as it sounds**, the 10 injections I had to get were painless.

It is usually used to speak about something bad, however, it can also be said **sarcastically** in a joking way for unbelievable good news

> P1: **As horrible as it sounds**, I won a week at a beach resort!
>   P2: Oh no, that's awful, poor you! *(sarcastic snicker)*

The construction is **as** *something* **as it sounds**

> **good
>
>   bad
>
>   wonderful
>
>   desperate
>
>   stupid
>
>   boring**
>   etc.

A similar idiom is: **as** *something* **as it gets**